# Access Themes/Generic.xaml via reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Is there any way to access the Themes/Generic `ResourceDictionary` using reflection?

I tried digging through `Application.Resources` but this appears to be the wrong place.
Then I tried analysing the Assembly's ResourceStream but that wasn't succesful either.

So does anyone know how I can get the instance of the mentioned `ResourceDictionary` from an assembly?

Before someone asks "Why" => because i want to mess with it.

This is the closest i got, but it throws errors that some parts of it cannot be loaded, so I assume its a "copy" and not the one used?

```
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/ASMNAME;component/themes/generic.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        ResourceDictionary dictionary =(ResourceDictionary) Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
```

Comment: Mate, my answer returns the actual ResourceDictionary - the same that FindResource does! It's originally compiled into the DLL! It's binary data! You have to read ite and convert it to XAML! Then you can parse this XAML and create an instance of ResourceDictionary! This is how it works. That's the same what the WPF framework is doing and what FindResource does!

Comment: It uses relection to return a ResourceDitionary of generic.xaml. See this line of code: `var genericXamlResources = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(themesBamlReader) as ResourceDictionary;` - before I extract the Style as an example.

Comment: @BionicCode not enitrely. The FrameWork uses a cached instance of it, that is accuired the way i posted in my answer. Adding a new style does not work with your soloution, since it is basically a copy, not the one used.
Check out what theese methods do, they use a dictionary behind the scenes.

I removed my downvote because you deleted all your personal comments

Answer (score 0):

The [provided solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70244285/3141792) of @CSharpie is slow as it uses reflection in order to invoke *internal* library code. But more important, its implementation is very unsafe and very unstable as it relies on non-public library code that can change at any time. Using such implementations in production code is irresponsible and unprofessional.
In case of the referenced answer, instead of using reflection to invoke the internals of `FrameworkElement.FindResource` simply invoke this method directly!

Better use the *public* API:

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyCustomControl}">
    ...
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The following code assumes that the *Generic.xaml* file is located in an assembly named "Net.Wpf". You can call `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames`
to get a list of existing resource names.
In the example, the required name is "Net.Wpf.g.resources".
Then lookup the resource like this:

```cs
// Get the assembly that contains the Themes/Generic.xaml file
Assembly themesAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
await using Stream themesResourceStream = themesAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Net.Wpf.g.resources");
using var resourceReader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(themesResourceStream);
await using var themesBamlStream = resourceReader
  .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
  .First(entry => entry.Key.Equals("themes/generic.baml"))
  .Value as Stream;
using var themesBamlReader = new System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader(themesBamlStream);
var genericXamlResources = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(themesBamlReader) as ResourceDictionary;
Style customControlStyle = genericXamlResources[typeof(MyCustomControl)] as Style;

// *******************************
// Same can be achieved by calling
Style customControlStyle = FindResource(typeof(ShortcutButton)) as Style;
```

Note, the XAML resource dictionaries (with build action set to "Page") are usually compiled to BAML (a binary format) before embedded into the assembly. You therefore must convert from BAML back to XAML before you can access the resources.

Comment: I was specifically asking for a way to do it via relfection because your mentioned way has no effect on runtime when altering the dictionaries content. Performance of reflection in this scenario is also more than negligible. Those few microseconds of overhead will go completely unnoticed.

Comment: @CSharpie *"Those few microseconds of overhead will go completely unnoticed"*, yes there are indeed more critical problems with your pseudo solution. I addressed them too not only the reflection costs.

Comment: what is the pseudo part of my soloution here, do you know my requirements? Also your answer does not answer my question. I need the used instance of the ResourceDicitonary, not a specific style.

Answer (score -2):

I got it working now

I found how to do it here:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemResources.cs,376

```
Assembly asm = .....
var systemResourcesType = typeof(Application).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.SystemResources");
var ensuremethod = systemResourcesType.GetMethod("EnsureDictionarySlot", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var loadMethod = ensuremethod.ReturnType.GetMethod("LoadGenericDictionary", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var resourceDictionaries = ensuremethod.Invoke(null, new[] { asm });

var resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)loadMethod.Invoke(resourceDictionaries, new object[]{false});
```

Comment: Instead of using reflection to invoke the internals of FrameworkElement.FindResource method, simply invoke this method directly! Relying on internal i.e. non-public code is a dangerous game. There is a public API to achieve this.